# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

Tags: jsf, pdf, jasper-reports, managed-bean

I'm trying to create a pdf export from A jsf page using jasper report.
and I was fighting to get the solution, so this is the stack after submit the button.

I'm using glassfich not jboss, and I use windows xp as an os, netbeans as an ide

```
 WARNING: #{domBean.print()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize    class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
javax.faces.FacesException: #{domBean.print()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could  not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at  com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 36 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
at com.cacib.managedbean.DomBean.print(DomBean.java:356)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 37 more

 WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet  Faces Servlet threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:705)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1161)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and the code of the managed bean is :

a public function witch trigger the PDF writing

```
public void print() {

    try {


        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        InputStream reportStream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/reports/avidCredit.jasper");
        System.out.println(reportStream);
        System.out.println(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath());

        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();


        String userName = "sa";
        String psw = "123456";

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.6:1433;databaseName=comex_cacib_dev";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, psw);


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try{
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, baos, new HashMap(), conn);
        reportStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
         response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=");
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);



        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

UPDATE : after i added the commons-diegest commons-beanutils commons-collection the stack turn to be like this :

```
WARNING: #{domBean.print()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
javax.faces.FacesException: #{domBean.print()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
at  com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at  com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
at     javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 36 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.<clinit>(ComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory.java:105)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:53)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:237)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:214)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:162)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:133)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:105)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:153)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:55)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:201)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:720)
at com.cacib.managedbean.DomBean.print(DomBean.java:356)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Rule
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
... 73 more

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet  Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3991: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:705)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:723)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1161)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at  com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: i'm using glassfich not jboss ,and i use windows xp as an os , netbeans as an ide

Comment: Even though that means my answer seems not to fit, I think the answer still is to be sought in the static initializer block of `JRStyledTextParser`. Do try to run the server in [Headless Mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html), it's worth a try.