# JasperReports: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I would like to share my experience with a more or less common error with JasperReports.

When executing JasperReports to make a PDF report, I have an exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.&lt;init&gt;(JRBaseFiller.java:108)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.&lt;init&gt;(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.&lt;init&gt;(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:200)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:215)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:115)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:667)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:983)
```

My environment :

- CentOs 6.6 - Kernel 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
- Java 1.7_79 (Sun)
- JasperReport 6.2.2
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.68

Same question that:

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276201/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-net-sf-jasperreports)
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536539/noclassdeffounderror-jrstyledtextparser-initialization-failure

I tried these solutions without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here some checks to do :

- Red Hat KB : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1311113. 

   VMWare KB : https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2010240.

   Your environment should have X11 and/or graphic packages (fonts etc.)  installed OR you have to run Java with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` option. With headless, your libraries needs to have fonts included (Default JasperReport font is Pictonic.ttf)
- Clean your Tomcat Cache and don't do hot deployment. Some JasperReport versions have memory leaks with ThreadLocal uses in some classes. See for example http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4403-0
- JRStyledTextParser have a static initializer which can mask some exceptions. It especially initializes the loading of fonts (on the OS or included in jar) in a cache by using Font implement in java.awt. But, see the source code of Font :

  ```
  private static boolean hasTempPermission() {

  if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
      return true;
  }
  File f = null;
  boolean hasPerm = false;
  try {
      f = Files.createTempFile("+~JT", ".tmp").toFile();
      f.delete();
      f = null;
      hasPerm = true;
  } catch (Throwable t) {
      /* inc. any kind of SecurityException */
  }
  return hasPerm;
  }
  ```

Java create temp file (using java.io.tmp option if you have specified it). So check that your temporary folder is not full and writable by the user/group of Java PID. If it is not the case, an exception will be thrown, but catched and invisible...

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue on my development machine. Basically it was happened due to problem in application server (**Apache tomcat**)

Basically I've accidentally deleted the "**temp**" folder in server root. So jasper cant compile the report and proceed with the report generation.

Also temp folder space can make a huge damage to report generation process.

So check following items in the server

1. Server space
2. Missing folders in tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after hours. If you use bitnami docker compose file, you must volume the java folder. Reports are running with java 1.8_201 version. So you should download 1.8_201 and volume it your docker compose.

```
volumes:
  - 'jasperreports_data:/bitnami/jasperreports'
  - '/path/your/downloaded/java:/opt/bitnami/java'
```